# How to play part of an audio file on mouseclick or mouseover on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I am creating a website for teaching some arabic words.  I am including numbers, ordinal numbers, days of the week etc. and I have a audio file that has them all and I would like to play it with mouseover or mouseclick. Now, I don't want to have cut the audio into many pieces to make this work. Is there a way to call an audio file on mouseclick or mouseover and only play the file partially? For example I have an audio file that has numbers from 1 to 10 and let's say each is a second long.  When user click on number 5, I want to be able to call the numbers audio file and play the 5th second and stop.  Is this possible? Following is my code that calls and plays the entire audio. Thank you!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Arabic Letters</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function playSound(soundfile) {
 document.getElementById("dummy").innerHTML=
 "<embed src=\""+soundfile+"\" hidden=\"true\" autostart=\"true\" loop=\"false\" />";
 }
 </script>

</head>

<body>
     <span id="dummy"></span> 

<a href="#" onclick="playSound('1-001_page3.mp3');"><p dir="rtl" lang="ar"
class="letter">واحِد</p></a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use something like [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/). It has an [`onProgressChange`](http://jplayer.org/0.2.4/developer-guide/#jPlayer-onProgressChange) that you can use to stop it after a certain time. You can use `playHeadTime` (same docs page) to move the play head around too. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599929/jplayer-play-between-certain-percents-of-time-in-jquery) for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a global variable to set the current stopping point and bind a `timeupdate` listener to check if the time has been reached:

```
var endTime = 0;
// do this binding once at page load time
myaudio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if(this.currentTime >= endTime) {
        this.pause();
    }
});
```

With each event, set start time with `myaudio.currentTime`, the end time with `endTime` and the `play()` the audio:

```
// plays the audioObj from start to stop times (in seconds)
// call this for each snippet you wish to play (e.g., in an onclick handler)
function playInterval (audioObj, start, stop) {
    audioObj.currentTime = start*1000;
    endTime = stop*1000;
    audio.play();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am new to javascript and trying to figure out your example. What argument am I supposed to pass for audioObj ?

Comment: You should give your `<audio>` tag an `id` property (like `<audio id="foo">`) and get it in JS with `var myAudioObj = document.getElementById("foo")`.  You'd use that object for `audioObj` and for `myaudio` in the event binding operation.